# findWithinHorizon - how's it working?

Tags: java

There is a code with myScanner.findWithinHorizon.charAt(1). I want to type in a word and then get the second (third, fourth, whatever) letter from that word. If there's .charAt(0), it works and returns the first letter.

Whenever I set a different .charAt(), it doesn't work: **Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 1**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    char c1;

    Scanner myScanner = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.print("Write something: ");

    c1 = myScanner.findWithinHorizon(".", 0).charAt(1);

    System.out.println(c1);

}
```

Thanks.

Comment: If you print `c1` before trying `charAt(1)`, what is `c1`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.` is a regex that means "1 char, whatever it is". So you're looking for the next char. So the returned string contains a single char. So attempting to get the char at index 1 is throwing this exception.

To get the next word, use `Scanner.next()`.

Answer (score 1):

It finds the next occurrence of regex. "." means take any next char

```
    Scanner myScanner = new Scanner("123");
    System.out.println(myScanner.findWithinHorizon(".", 0));
    System.out.println(myScanner.findWithinHorizon(".", 0));
    System.out.println(myScanner.findWithinHorizon(".", 0));
    System.out.println(myScanner.findWithinHorizon(".", 0));
```

output

```
1
2
3
null
```

Comment: I see. When I want to take only the second char ('2', should I use Scanner.next() ?

Comment: no, just call myScanner.findWithinHorizon(".", 0); once and ignore the returned value

Comment: By deleting ".charAt(0)" I have to convert c1 to a string. Then I write "Hello" and it returns "H". I want "E". How to do it?

Comment: myScanner.findWithinHorizon(".", 0); String e = myScanner.findWithinHorizon(".", 0);

Comment: Thanks, it works. It is not possible to "merge" these two lines into one? I mean, if I wrote "Possibly" and I wanted only the fifth char "i", I'd have to write 5 lines of code?

Comment: for this purpose the easiest solution is myScanner.nextLine().charAt(4);